# Moving a shape when running a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to "unlock" a fixed image on an already running userform so that I can move it around freely and after clicking it again, cause it to be in a fixed position again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think that this does what you are looking for.

```
Dim imgOriginX As Double
Dim imgOriginY As Double
Dim clicked As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    clicked = False
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     If clicked = True Then
        imgOriginX = X
        imgOriginY = Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If clicked = True Then
        clicked = False
    Else
        clicked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     If clicked = True Then
        If Button And 1 Then
            Image1.Left = Image1.Left + (X - imgOriginX)
            Image1.Top = Image1.Top + (Y - imgOriginX)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have to try this out later when I'm free. I was actually able to come up with a rudimentary way of what I was trying to accomplish, though it's rather impractical but fits the purpose of what I was initially trying to do. I'll post what I came up with as well, but as I mentioned I'll try what you provided in a bit.

Comment: I found even smoother method, edited post. this should work perfectly, let me know!

Comment: Interesting. It's definitely a much better approach then my design. I wonder if there's a way to define it where you don't have to "click" the image before you can move it around. I'll definitely play around with this.

Comment: make a new question and I can post answer to that question!

Comment: why not just edit your original answer and post whatever you need to below the one you provided?

Comment: #1 it is a seperate anwser to seperate question. if in future someone looks for anwser to question they will have harder time finding it. #2 more rep points! sometimes incentive structures work as intended...:-)

Comment: ahhh gotcha. Yeah one sec, ill make a new question